# gradle.properties file not being read

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle.properties

I have recently moved to a new laptop and is facing issue with setting up gradle 7.6.4 on intellij. I had no issues with the setup in my old laptop. I have gradle.properties file in C:\Users\username\ .gradle with artifactory_user=user
artifactory_password=pass
artifactory_contextUrl=url
From intellij when i import an existing gradle project it gives me error

```
Could not get unknown property ‘artifactoryUser’ for settings 
‘projectname’ of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.
```

I tried hardcoding the username and password. Then it fails in the first line of build.gradle where it is unable to download plugin. I believe something is wrong with the initialization of gradle. I am using correct java version. I tried accessing properties and it returns null

```
println(settings.hasProperty(‘artifactory_password’) ? settings.artifactory_password : ‘’)
println(hasProperty(‘artifactory_user’) ? artifactory_user : ‘’)
```

Comment: Have you noticed the difference in camel-case (e.g. `artifactoryUser`) vs. snake-case (e.g. `artifactory_user`)?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you specify those properties in a gradle.properties file located directly in your Project's directory? Also, does the issue persist if you run Gradle from PowerShell / Windows Terminal?

Comment: @BjørnVester Yes i was trying both ways- i should probably edit the post if i can to update them all to snake-case artifactory_user. All the properties are in snake-case

Comment: @romanv-jb  I did try placing gradle.properties in my projects root directory. Did not see a difference. I tried running from windows terminal and got the same error